# Unregister zoom listener and restore scroll ability in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently working D3.js. This is the code to register zoom listener for my svg tag

```
var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom);
function zoom() {
  vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
svg.call(zoomListener)
```

Now when I scroll the mouse on the svg element, it is zoomed. But when I unbind the zoom event like this

```
zoomListener.on("zoom", null);
```

only the svg is not zoomed but I cannot scroll the page while the mouse is over the svg element.

How to unbind the zoom listener and restore the scroll ability for the mouse? thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To completely disable the zoom behaviour, you need to unregister all event handlers that it has installed on the element you've called it on:

```
svg.on("mousedown.zoom", null);
svg.on("mousemove.zoom", null);
svg.on("dblclick.zoom", null);
svg.on("touchstart.zoom", null);
svg.on("wheel.zoom", null);
svg.on("mousewheel.zoom", null);
svg.on("MozMousePixelScroll.zoom", null);
```

Comment: This didn't work,  in fact there were some errors in firebug console with this.  I found a question which is exactly same as my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25424524/1369473  There has been no reply to it, yet.  :(

Comment: This solution is perfect for selectively disabling only mouse scroll and having drag still work.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior, all you need to do is

```
svg.on(".zoom", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I **vastly** appreciate Lars's solution, but neither he nor the asker goes on to explain the definition of `svg` so I'm posting this for those who want some clarity.

I have a Rickshaw graph rendered in `$("#my-graphing-div")` (based on `d3`) and this is how I remove scrolling events:

```
var svg = $("#my-graphing-div").children("svg");
d3.select(svg[0])
    .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
    .on("mousemove.zoom", null)
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("touchstart.zoom", null)
    .on("wheel.zoom", null)
    .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
    .on("MozMousePixelScroll.zoom", null);
```

Using `d3.select` prior to `on` was the key to fixing it for me. Huge props you guys, this post really helped me out.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, at least provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.enableZoomInteraction(false)` to disable scroll zoom mouse event if you're use force-graph like me.:)